# How to turn a timestamp string like 3/25/2019 11:00 AM into a timestamp

Tags: datetime, time

I have a column of timestamps called date_subscribed, in string format:

date_subscribed
2/12/2019 9:38 AM
3/5/2019 1:32 PM
3/12/2019 2:18 PM
3/25/2019 11:00 AM
3/26/2019 10:22 AM

I want to convert them into timestamps and compare them with timestamps of the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC. Alternatively I can also just use the date part of the data and compare with YYYY-MM-DD. What's the best way to convert?

I've tried two approaches: first:

```
example_date = temp_table_head['date_subscribed'][3]
print(example_date)
example_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(example_date, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
example_date
```

Second:

```
example_date = temp_table_head['date_subscribed'][3]
print(example_date)
example_date=example_date.split(' ')[0]
print(example_date)
example_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(example_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
example_date
```

Both of these work for the first 3 data points but not the last two. The error I get is **ValueError: time data '3/25/2019' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which tool and/or script language are you using? Please add appropriate tags to your question so that folks who know about it get aware of your question. It’s your best chance to get qualified answers.

Comment: if this is Python/pandas, just use `df['date_subscribed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_subscribed'])` to convert to pandas' datetime data type and make it comparable to pd.Timestamp objects